# Updated component variable in JQuery sortable stop event

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to change the isMyPresentationEmpty variable when the stop event of JQuery sortable fires. Unfortunately the 'this' variable is undefined in that scope... Do you know how I am able to access the variable from that scope?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Inject } from 'angular2/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'edit-presentation',
    templateUrl: 'app/Edit Presentation/edit_presentation.component.html'
})
export class EditPresentationComponent implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    isMyPresentationEmpty = true;

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        // Initialize Sortable on lists
        var oldList, newList, item;
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.sortable-list').sortable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
                item = ui.item;
                newList = oldList = ui.item.parent().parent();
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {  
                if (ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent().parent();

            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {  
                // Check for empty list and hide/show instruction text
                if (jQuery(event.target).has('li').length) {
                    this.isMyPresentationEmpty = false;
                } else {
                    this.isMyPresentationEmpty = true;
                }
            },
            connectWith: ".sortable-list"
        }).disableSelection();
    }

}
```

Comment: jQuery inside Angular2 ?!? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind "this" to a variable (var self in this example) outside your events and then use that variable inside the events. For example:

```
ngOnInit() {
        var self = this;  //use self instead of this if you want to refer to your component inside events
        // Initialize Sortable on lists
        var oldList, newList, item;
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.sortable-list').sortable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
                item = ui.item;
                newList = oldList = ui.item.parent().parent();
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {  
                if (ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent().parent();

            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {  
                // Check for empty list and hide/show instruction text
                if (jQuery(event.target).has('li').length) {
                    self.isMyPresentationEmpty = false;
                } else {
                    self.isMyPresentationEmpty = true;
                }
            },
            connectWith: ".sortable-list"
        }).disableSelection();
    }
```

Comment: This is the JS way... You can just use arrow-functions in typescript that do not change the this context in a function.

Comment: @Dinistro Yes but then you have to do other adjustments for example if you want to select $(this) = $(event.target). That may have been a case so I stayed on the safe side.

Comment: Oh, of course. I was not thinking about this. This is perhaps the reason, why using JQuery in angular2 is not that nice.

Comment: Indeed. I agree :)

Comment: If I could have avoided JQuery I would have. But I could not find any Angular2 solution for making my lists sortable...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [arrow-functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html) from typescript, the do not change the this.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Inject } from 'angular2/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'edit-presentation',
    templateUrl: 'app/Edit Presentation/edit_presentation.component.html'
})
export class EditPresentationComponent implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    isMyPresentationEmpty = true;

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        // Initialize Sortable on lists
        var oldList, newList, item;
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.sortable-list').sortable({
            start: (event, ui) => {
                item = ui.item;
                newList = oldList = ui.item.parent().parent();
            },
            change: (event, ui) => {
                if (ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent().parent();

            },
            stop: (event, ui) => {
                // Check for empty list and hide/show instruction text
                if (jQuery(event.target).has('li').length) {
                    this.isMyPresentationEmpty = false;
                } else {
                    this.isMyPresentationEmpty = true;
                }
            },
            connectWith: ".sortable-list"
        }).disableSelection();
    }

}
```

Setting the this into a variable is a JavaScript solution and not the typescript way.

I hope this helped you.